# using Oracle Exadata and C#: Paging data from Oracle to retrieve in datatable

Tags: c#, oracle

I am using Oracle Exadata as database and using that in a ASP.NET C# Web application. 
I am trying to query the data from the database and fetch the data in data table. The data is too huge as I am using a select * option. The data table errors out with memory issues and would not be the right approach as well.

I am trying to check if a paging model can be applied.

I have used the below code model with MS SQL, which works. I am not sure how this can be applied in Oracle query. Below is the code for MS SQL.

```
    public List<DataTable> GetDataSet()
    {
        var dataTables = new List<DataTable>();
        var totalRecords = 0;
        var tableIndex = 1;

        using (var cn = new SqlConnection {ConnectionString = ConnectionString})
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand {Connection = cn})
            {
                var selectStatement =
                    @"SELECT Cust.CustomerIdentifier,
                        Cust.CompanyName,
                        Cust.ContactName,
                        C.[Name] AS Country
                    FROM dbo.Customers AS Cust
                         INNER JOIN dbo.Countries AS C 
                            ON Cust.CountryIdentifier = C.CountryIdentifier
                    ORDER BY Cust.CustomerIdentifier
                    OFFSET @Offset ROWS 
                    FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY;";

                var countStatement = "SELECT COUNT(Cust.CustomerIdentifier) FROM dbo.Customers AS Cust";
                cmd.CommandText = countStatement;

                cn.Open();

                totalRecords = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                cmd.CommandText = selectStatement;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@OffSet", SqlDbType.Int);
                for (var index = 0; index < totalRecords; index++)
                {
                    if (index % 25 == 0)
                    {

                        cmd.Parameters["@OffSet"].Value = index;
                        var dt = new DataTable() {TableName = $"Table{tableIndex}"};
                        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                        dataTables.Add(dt);
                        tableIndex += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return dataTables;
    }
```

I am trying to achieve the same functionality with Oracle. How to query the Oracle to get the data in this same way. Thanks

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  The `OFFSET` syntax is valid in Oracle 12c.  The only obvious issue I see with the SQL statement is that `C.[Name] ` will not work in Oracle.  If the column name is case sensitive then use double quotes instead of square brackets.

Comment: Thanks. yes, I am using Oracle 12c. If the query is a simple select * from table, how to modify the query statement.

Comment: If you try it with `C.Name` I think it might work.  Your SQL code looks really close to working.  You should try it out and modify the question with the error message, if any.